# GWT get started eclipse problem

Tags: eclipse, gwt

was followin this tutorial

http://code.google.com/intl/et-EE/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html

when i run my program in browser by IP , the application works
[image]

but when i compile it and run it in producution mode, it says that server isn't running
[image]

anyone knows the solution? or what i am doing wrong?

server i think is jetty, it comes with GWT by default

```
Initializing AppEngine server
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
 Successfully processed C:\Users\Jansu\Documents\workspace\gtw-test\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
 Successfully processed C:\Users\Jansu\Documents\workspace\gtw-test\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use TomCat, Glassfish, or jetty to run the web server.

Comment: it should be jetty as default..since it did run at localhost:8080 ... isnt it the same thing? same serveR?

Comment: In eclipse image it looks like you open the html file bypassing the server. In order to work, you have to navigate to http://localhost:8080/gtw-test or something similar - depends on context path.

Comment: @jjczopek : but when you look at the tutorial http://code.google.com/intl/et-EE/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html, and scroll down to "Compile and run in Production Mode" , you can see that it is written there ::: "To see the final application, open the file MyWebApp/war/MyWebApp.html in your web browser."

Comment: @Jaanus: keep reading the next paragraph next to the one you just quoted. Your computer can only serve the javascript, but you need to setup the actual Java web server. 
GWT does provide Jetty for production, but you would need to setup your own Jetty server to provide the web pages in deployment.